# How can I read an Oracle SQL Developer view into R?

Tags: r

The dbReadTable() function allows me to read tables but not views from sql developer ? Which function should I use, please ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [RODBC Package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf). Views are treated like tables, so you can just read it in using SQL Fetch.

Comment: Thank you so much @Foxhound for your help !  Have a nice day !